# Как перенести БД из xamarin в нативное андроид приложение?

Tags: android, xamarin

У меня есть 2 приложения, одно на xamarin, второе нативное.
На девайсе установлено xamarin версия, там есть какие-то данные в БД.

Я сделал одинаковые пакеты для обоих версий, увеличил версию нативного прилоежния на 1.
НО при установке нативного приложения, старое удаляется.
Как сделать так, чтобы новое записывалось поверх старого и данные из БД сохранились??

Comment: В каком смысле удаляется? Для успешного обновления кроме того же пакета нужно использовать ещё и тот же сертификат при создании подписанной версии.

Comment: @woesss при установке новой версии, студия говорит, что необходимо предыдущую удалить, чтобы установить нативную.
Я знаю, что в рилиз версии там можно уже конкретными ключами подписать и, скорее всего, будет друг на друга меняться, а что в случае дебага?
При дебаге студия своим ключом подписывает, VIsual Studio (xamarin) свой ключ, Android Studio(свой ключ)
как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: Подписывать тем же ключем, тогда ничего не будет удаляться. И не важно какой он (дебаг или релиз), просто оно должен быть тем же.

Comment: В меню "Project Structure" можно создать signing configuration, в которой можно задать любой keystore и ключ. Потом выбрать эту конфигурацию для билд типа `debug` в том же меню. Или тоже самое можно описать ручками в `build.gradle`